# Convert from code page 437 to unicode with boost

Tags: c++, boost, icu

How can I use `boost::locale::conv::to_utf` in order to convert a CP437 string into unicode?

I have a `std::string` which contains the CP437 encoded string "äöü". The corresponding UTF16 encoding is 0x00e4, 0x00f6, 0x00fc. I tried both

```
std::wstring str_utf = boost::locale::conv::to_utf<wchar_t>(str_437, "CP437");
```

and

```
boost::locale::generator gen;
std::locale loc = gen.generate("CP437");
std::wstring str_utf = boost::locale::conv::to_utf<wchar_t>(str_437, loc);
```

to convert the string into a unicode string, but it didnt work: The first method returned the wrong `wchar_t` values 0x0004, 0x0014, 0x0001 and the second method failed with `abort() has been called`.

I also tried variations of the "CP437" string, for example, ".CP437", "cp437", ".cp437", etc, but none of them worked.

I first thought that maybe my string is not encoded in CP437 at all, but then I converted the string using the ICU library and it successfully yielded the correct UTF16 values 0x00e4, 0x00f6, 0x00fc.

Why does boost fail while ICU succeeds for the same string? Do I need to use different code page identifiers for boost?

Comment: Do you really need to use boost locale? Or you simply need to transcode some symbols. You can use IBM ICU (the library boost locale based on) or iconv or MS Mlang (if your program is widows only).

Comment: I dont need to use boost locale, but it would be very convenient, because I already depend on other boost libraries. I dont want to introduce another library if boost locale already solves the problem.